# node.js express как подключить https?

Tags: node.js, https, ssl

Пытаюсь так:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

var server = require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'sslcert/server.key')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'sslcert/server.crt'))
},app);
server.listen(80);
```

Но ничего не выходит =(

Есть идеи как запустить сертификат на ноде?

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос, поменял порт с 80 на 443